# Keras character level LSTM text classification not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, text-classification

I am making a keras model for character level text classification using LSTM (my first model). The model is supposed to classify normal, spam, and rude messages from a twitch chat. However the results I am getting are quite disappointing and confusing.

The LSTM network learns very little and the accuracy is horrible no matter what I do.

This is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
''' import tensorflowjs.converters '''
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import json
import numpy as np
import re
import random
import sys

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

vocab = " qwertyuiopasdfghjklñzxcvbnmç1234567890?¿¡!,:-+/@#áéíóú\/"

dropout = 0.2

x_train = []
y_train = []
one_hot_encode = []
sentence = []

# amount of examples in each class
maxofeachtype = 1600

countnormal = 0
countspam = 0
countofensivo = 0

# Load dataset from data.json
with open("./data.json", 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# suffle it
random.shuffle(data)

# create the vocabulary map
mapping = {}
for x in range(len(vocab)):
    mapping[vocab[x]] = x

# this is some to balance the dataset adjusting it to "maxofeachtype"
for example in data:
    if(example["y"] == [1, 0, 0] and countnormal < maxofeachtype):
        countnormal += 1
    elif(example["y"] == [0, 1, 0] and countspam < maxofeachtype):
        countspam += 1
    elif(example["y"] == [0, 0, 1] and countofensivo < maxofeachtype):
        countofensivo += 1
    elif(countnormal == maxofeachtype or countspam == maxofeachtype or countofensivo == maxofeachtype):
        continue

    # remove unwanted characters to only have the ones in vocab
    cleanexample = re.sub(
        r'[^qwertyuiopasdfghjklñzxcvbnmç1234567890?¿¡!,:@#áéíóú\/]', '', str(example["x"]))

    # if the sentence is less than 500 characters long (the max you can type in twitch) add spaces until it gets to 500 chars long
    if len(cleanexample) != 500:
        for a in range(500 - len(cleanexample)):
            cleanexample = cleanexample + " "
    for character in cleanexample:
        sentence.append(mapping[character])

    # print(sentence)
    y_train_ohe = tf.one_hot(sentence, depth=len(vocab)).numpy()
    # print(y_train_ohe)
    x_train.append(y_train_ohe)
    y_train.append(np.array(example["y"]))
    sentence = []

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
""" print(x_train[0][0:5], x_train[0][-5:], y_train[0]) """
print(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

# Create the model
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.LSTM(256, activation="tanh",
                      return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout, input_shape=(500, 57)))

model.add(layers.LSTM(128, activation="tanh",
                      return_sequences=False, dropout=dropout))

model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=15, shuffle=True,
          batch_size=25, validation_split=0.2)

model.save('model_py.h5')

''' tensorflowjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "./modelo_js") '''
```

The training samples look like this before processing. [1, 0, 0] means normal, [0, 1, 0] rude language and [0, 0, 1] means spam:

```
"x": "sentence",
        "y": [
            1,
            0,
            0
        ]
```

And they look like this after processing. I one hot encode them to a vector length of 57, the vocabulary size. The arrays starting with 1 are spaces:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
  ....
 [1 0 0]
```

And after training with 1600 examples of each class and validation_split = 0.2 these are the results:

```
(4800, 500, 57)
(4800, 3)
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 500, 256)          321536
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               197120
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 387
=================================================================
Total params: 519,043
Trainable params: 519,043
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/15
2020-09-09 12:35:47.606648: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-09-09 12:35:47.872095: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
154/154 [==============================] - 13s 87ms/step - loss: 1.0811 - accuracy: 0.4120 - val_loss: 2.0132 - val_accuracy: 0.0219
Epoch 2/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 78ms/step - loss: 1.0577 - accuracy: 0.4177 - val_loss: 2.0314 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 76ms/step - loss: 1.0457 - accuracy: 0.4154 - val_loss: 1.6968 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 76ms/step - loss: 1.0506 - accuracy: 0.4161 - val_loss: 1.7731 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/15
154/154 [==============================] - 11s 73ms/step - loss: 1.0511 - accuracy: 0.4313 - val_loss: 1.9052 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 75ms/step - loss: 1.0473 - accuracy: 0.4104 - val_loss: 1.6291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/15
154/154 [==============================] - 13s 84ms/step - loss: 1.0464 - accuracy: 0.4135 - val_loss: 1.8916 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 76ms/step - loss: 1.0404 - accuracy: 0.4208 - val_loss: 1.8094 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 76ms/step - loss: 1.0449 - accuracy: 0.4096 - val_loss: 1.9690 - val_accuracy: 0.0219
Epoch 10/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 77ms/step - loss: 1.0489 - accuracy: 0.4104 - val_loss: 1.9596 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/15
154/154 [==============================] - 13s 83ms/step - loss: 1.0455 - accuracy: 0.4141 - val_loss: 1.8082 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 76ms/step - loss: 1.0465 - accuracy: 0.4219 - val_loss: 1.7066 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 75ms/step - loss: 1.0424 - accuracy: 0.4161 - val_loss: 1.5192 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 75ms/step - loss: 1.0481 - accuracy: 0.4154 - val_loss: 1.5999 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/15
154/154 [==============================] - 12s 77ms/step - loss: 1.0476 - accuracy: 0.4008 - val_loss: 2.0612 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

The weird thing is that if I increase the validation split the results improve. This makes no sense to me because it's less training data.

This is with validation_split = 0.6

```
77/77 [==============================] - 8s 103ms/step - loss: 1.0352 - accuracy: 0.4432 - val_loss: 1.4233 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 2/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 93ms/step - loss: 0.9906 - accuracy: 0.4443 - val_loss: 1.7316 - val_accuracy: 0.2937
Epoch 3/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 92ms/step - loss: 0.9863 - accuracy: 0.4812 - val_loss: 1.5367 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 4/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 94ms/step - loss: 0.9874 - accuracy: 0.4635 - val_loss: 1.4075 - val_accuracy: 0.2937
Epoch 5/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 93ms/step - loss: 0.9905 - accuracy: 0.4594 - val_loss: 1.5759 - val_accuracy: 0.2937
Epoch 6/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 93ms/step - loss: 0.9808 - accuracy: 0.4703 - val_loss: 1.3886 - val_accuracy: 0.2937
Epoch 7/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 96ms/step - loss: 0.9815 - accuracy: 0.4781 - val_loss: 1.2495 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 8/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 96ms/step - loss: 0.9824 - accuracy: 0.4698 - val_loss: 1.4516 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 9/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 92ms/step - loss: 0.9916 - accuracy: 0.4573 - val_loss: 1.4488 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 10/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 90ms/step - loss: 0.9858 - accuracy: 0.4760 - val_loss: 1.3868 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 11/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 93ms/step - loss: 0.9861 - accuracy: 0.4734 - val_loss: 1.5702 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 12/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 91ms/step - loss: 0.9880 - accuracy: 0.4630 - val_loss: 1.4439 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 13/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 91ms/step - loss: 0.9796 - accuracy: 0.4865 - val_loss: 1.3597 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 14/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 91ms/step - loss: 0.9832 - accuracy: 0.4745 - val_loss: 1.5791 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
Epoch 15/15
77/77 [==============================] - 7s 90ms/step - loss: 0.9919 - accuracy: 0.4760 - val_loss: 1.6243 - val_accuracy: 0.2313
```

And with validation_split = 0.8

```
39/39 [==============================] - 7s 171ms/step - loss: 1.1238 - accuracy: 0.4484 - val_loss: 1.3041 - val_accuracy: 0.3158
Epoch 2/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 143ms/step - loss: 0.9795 - accuracy: 0.4692 - val_loss: 1.2562 - val_accuracy: 0.3174
Epoch 3/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 146ms/step - loss: 0.9757 - accuracy: 0.4724 - val_loss: 1.3583 - val_accuracy: 0.3437
Epoch 4/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 149ms/step - loss: 0.9741 - accuracy: 0.4703 - val_loss: 1.3565 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 5/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 148ms/step - loss: 0.9748 - accuracy: 0.4578 - val_loss: 1.3904 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 6/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 137ms/step - loss: 0.9697 - accuracy: 0.4755 - val_loss: 1.3418 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 7/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 136ms/step - loss: 0.9716 - accuracy: 0.4765 - val_loss: 1.3053 - val_accuracy: 0.3262
Epoch 8/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 136ms/step - loss: 0.9748 - accuracy: 0.4557 - val_loss: 1.3529 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 9/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 140ms/step - loss: 0.9768 - accuracy: 0.4505 - val_loss: 1.3260 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 10/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 136ms/step - loss: 0.9724 - accuracy: 0.4859 - val_loss: 1.3351 - val_accuracy: 0.3627
Epoch 11/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 143ms/step - loss: 0.9748 - accuracy: 0.4588 - val_loss: 1.3203 - val_accuracy: 0.3770
Epoch 12/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 144ms/step - loss: 0.9690 - accuracy: 0.4640 - val_loss: 1.3207 - val_accuracy: 0.3517
Epoch 13/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 137ms/step - loss: 0.9661 - accuracy: 0.4369 - val_loss: 1.3153 - val_accuracy: 0.3681
Epoch 14/15
39/39 [==============================] - 6s 141ms/step - loss: 0.9628 - accuracy: 0.4661 - val_loss: 1.3405 - val_accuracy: 0.2976
Epoch 15/15
39/39 [==============================] - 5s 137ms/step - loss: 0.9625 - accuracy: 0.4703 - val_loss: 1.3586 - val_accuracy: 0.3457
```

I've tried using just dense layers and the results are so much better which to me doesn't make sense because they cannot understand sequences. However this clears up the option of the dataset being bad.

With this configuration (validation_split back to 0.2):

```
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Input(shape=(500, 57)))

model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))

model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))

model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I get these results:

```
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7377 - accuracy: 0.7844 - val_loss: 1.4061 - val_accuracy: 0.0250
Epoch 2/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3479 - accuracy: 0.8448 - val_loss: 0.8703 - val_accuracy: 0.6927
Epoch 3/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3033 - accuracy: 0.8794 - val_loss: 1.4597 - val_accuracy: 0.6938
Epoch 4/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2899 - accuracy: 0.8966 - val_loss: 1.6684 - val_accuracy: 0.4896
Epoch 5/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2447 - accuracy: 0.9042 - val_loss: 1.6465 - val_accuracy: 0.4812
Epoch 6/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2269 - accuracy: 0.9211 - val_loss: 3.9954 - val_accuracy: 0.7312
Epoch 7/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2071 - accuracy: 0.9201 - val_loss: 2.7729 - val_accuracy: 0.4698
Epoch 8/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2081 - accuracy: 0.9302 - val_loss: 5.1325 - val_accuracy: 0.4229
Epoch 9/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1581 - accuracy: 0.9378 - val_loss: 4.4410 - val_accuracy: 0.3688
Epoch 10/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2184 - accuracy: 0.9333 - val_loss: 2.6669 - val_accuracy: 0.5396
Epoch 11/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1673 - accuracy: 0.9341 - val_loss: 3.6476 - val_accuracy: 0.2750
Epoch 12/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2111 - accuracy: 0.9443 - val_loss: 1.6768 - val_accuracy: 0.6885
Epoch 13/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1210 - accuracy: 0.9547 - val_loss: 2.6785 - val_accuracy: 0.5406
Epoch 14/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1179 - accuracy: 0.9542 - val_loss: 3.4468 - val_accuracy: 0.4385
Epoch 15/15
154/154 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1265 - accuracy: 0.9469 - val_loss: 2.0159 - val_accuracy: 0.7083
```

The model changes val_accuracy quite a bit but at least I know it is learning something.

I've tried (with the LSTM model):

-Changing the number of layers
-Changing the number of neurons of each layer
-Changing the learning rate
-Changing the optimizer to SGD
-Changing the loss function
-Changing the number of epochs
-Changing the number of training samples (duplicating each sample)
-Using decay in Adam

Comment: If the model doesn't work with LSTM then don't use LSTM layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems I see here:

- LSTMs don't work well with one-hot input. Use [padded](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences) [sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) (e.g., `[5, 6, 8]`)
- You need an [embedding layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) before the LSTM layers

Changing only the data (and loss function), I made an example that works based on your architecture (with an added embedding layer):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import sys

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

X_train = ['They like my dog', 'I hate my cat', 'We will love my hamster', 
           'I dislike your llama']
X_test = ['We love our hamster', 'They hate our platypus']
y_train = [1, 0, 1, 0]
y_test = [1, 0]

labels = {0: 'negative', 1: 'positive'}

encoder = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()

encoder.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = encoder.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = encoder.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

max_length = max(map(len, X_train))

x_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_length)
x_test = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_length)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

embedding_dim = 4
# print(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])
print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

# Create the model
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Embedding(len(encoder.index_word) + 1, embedding_dim))

model.add(layers.LSTM(8, activation="tanh",
                      return_sequences=True, dropout=.2))

model.add(layers.LSTM(8, activation="tanh",
                      return_sequences=False, dropout=.2))

model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.build(input_shape=x_train.shape)
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=25, shuffle=True,
          batch_size=25, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

Comment: Using and embedding layer and the keras encoder with char_level = True worked. Making the network smaller also made a difference. I got 85% accuracy. The text_to_sequences and pad_sequences functions also made my code more compact. Thank you so much.